# Video playing faster than sound in VLC Player

Tags: video, vlc

I've googled this issue and most of the time people have faster audio but slower video. For me it's the other way around. It doesn't matter what type of files I play.

I would be glad to put up more info if you guys need it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is adjusting the audio delay using J and K keys a viable solution to your problem?

Comment: That works perfect! Is there a way to set it to start with a certain delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sync the audio using the Adjustment and Effects panel of VLC. Click the Show extended settings button. Go to the Syncronization tab and adjust things manually until the audio and video line up for you.

[image: VLC Syncronization dialog]

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why this happens though?

Comment: @James I'm speculating, but it might be a problem with your audio drivers. I'm really not sure though, sorry.